# Interrupting a thread doesn't work after pushing a (applet) button

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, interrupt

I made a simple programm to let java play some .mp3 files. 
Using JLayer to get this right. 
The problem is that i can't interrupt my player after pushing a button.

my code in actionperformed:

```
    class MyThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                File file = new File(source);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    try {
                        Player player = new Player(bis);
                        player.play();
                    } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Came");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                lab2.setText("error, is the pathway correct?");
            }

        }
    }

    MyThread mythread = new MyThread();

    if (event.getSource() == input) {
        source = input.getText();
        source = source.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        lab1.setText(source);
    }

    if (event.getSource() == but1) {

        mythread.start();

    }

    if (event.getSource() == but2) {
        but2.setLabel("stop");
        mythread.interrupt();
        but2.setLabel("stopped");
    }
}
```

}

When I add the mythread.interrupt(); directly behind the interrupt works and my system gives me the "came" output.
But if I use my button called input, it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that player class doesnt have a stop method, but you can try with AdvancedPlayer:

http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/advanced/AdvancedPlayer.html

and the `stop()` method.